# What is the crew complement and capacity of the Galaxy class?

Tags: star-trek

The Galaxy class star ship typically had a complement of just over 1000, made up of officers, enlisted crew and civilians. But what would the standard ratios be for these groups?
(officers and enlisted may be combined for a single "crew" count)

I had assumed for years that the "crew" complement was only around 200-300, with the rest being civilians, but I cannot seem to locate any official numbers to confirm or deny this assumption.

Additionally, what is the maximum capacity of the Galaxy class? [Memory-Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Galaxy_class) lists it as 3000, [Memory-Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Galaxy_class) at 15000 (evacuation limit), and [Yesterday's Enterprise](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/163.htm) quoted 6000 troops (presumably in addition to standard crew).

Comment: Well, **"evacuation limit"** I would expect to be a lot higher. If they're trying to evacuate someplace in short order, I'd assume they'd have as many people as possible crammed into every cargo bay and hold and empty corner. They'd then go to offload them as soon as possible.

Comment: Yesterday's Enterprise is set in a parallel universe where the ship had been built as a battleship - so the spacious living quarters of the regular enterprise could easily have been replaced by bunkrooms to accommodate the 6,000 troops quoted

Comment: No source, so won't post this as an answer, but I'd say it's pretty safe to assume that about 1/3 to 1/2 of that would be actual crew. Not everyone is married, not everyone has children, so I think that should keep the ratio pretty close to one civilian per crew member. Add in some other non-crew scientists and similar, and it might drop the ratio below 50%.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Galaxy Class Starship**

From the Star Trek:  The Next Generation Technical Manual

**MISSION OBJECTIVES FOR GALAXY CLASS PROJECT**

- Standard crew complement approximately 1000 humanoids.
- Sufficient space for 200 additional crew for specific missions.
- Maximum staffing would place 3 crewmen to each quarters for 3000 total.

The ship environmental systems are capable of supporting up to 5000 life forms without strain for mission-related operations.

**Section 16.5 Rescue and Evac Operation**

- The Galaxy Class starship can transport 15,000 people during a medium level evacuation mission, transporting 1250 people per hour using transporters and shuttlecraft.
- Ship has the ability to convert secondary shuttlebays and holodecks into emergency triage centers. There is sufficiently cross-trained crew to staff said triage units.
- Ship has sufficient space using Shuttlebays and Cargo areas to convert to Class H, K, or L environmental conditions.

**SPECULATION:**

- Crew complement mixture is not specified, but if it is anything like the modern military, the ratio of officers to crew is approximately 1 officer to three technical crewmen.
- Family complements are not specified but given the environmental capacity of the Galaxy-class, even if their numbers were in the 500-1000 during normal underway missions the ship is more than capable of supporting them without difficulty.
- If the Galaxy Class were acting as a troop carrier, 6000 units plus their weapons, support equipment and vehicles seems reasonable if the cargo facilities were cleared of non-essential equipment.