# Crew rank distribution of the Enterprise D (or Galaxy-class)?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, uss-enterprise

We know that a Galaxy-class starship has a crew complement of about 1,000 members, (see [What is the crew complement and capacity of the Galaxy class?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52605/what-is-the-crew-complement-and-capacity-of-the-galaxy-class)), but what about the distribution of these 1,000 people - in principle, or on the Enterprise-D - with regard to rank?

I know, I know - most specific positions have a range of possible ranks: the Chief of Engineering or Ship's Doctor might not even have to be an officer; the Chief of Security can be as low as a Lieutenant (perhaps even a Lieutenant JG, although I doubt it) etc. Which is why I focused on the Enterprise-D.

What do we know about the numbers of each of the following?

- Officers (Commanders, Lt. Commanders, Lieutenants, Lieutenants Junior Grade,  Ensigns)
- Petty Officers (Master, Senior, Chief, 1st class, 2nd class)
- Crewmen (1st, 2nd, 3rd class)
- Civilian crew members (i.e. not passengers/crew families etc., but not members of Starfleet)

Comment: There's 1 captain.

Comment: @Valorum: You'll notice I didn't ask about captains...

Comment: I thought it might be helpful to note.

Comment: I know that in one episode one of the servers in 10-Forward specifically mentions he's _not_ Starfleet, but various Navies actually have crewmen barbers, etc, so it's not unreasonable for Mr Mott to be Starfleet crew, for example.

Comment: Since on-screen canon only mentions a total, the only sources would be off-screen - production "bible", licensed media such as novels and video games, or unlicensed media such as fan-fiction. Which sources would you consider acceptable for an answer (if there is one)?

Comment: @AnthonyX: Production "bible" certainly. Quotes from Rodenberry and other heads of the production or writing teams. Licensed novels and video games - for lack of a stronger source. Unlicensed media - not acceptable.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no canon answer. We don't even know how many civilians (i.e. crew families) are onboard.

FWIW, in US Wet Navy, the ratio is 1 officer to every 10 enlisted. Ticonderoga class CG has 30 officers and 300 enlisted.

Comment: As for the ratio of Officers, I have been doing some research on this very subject for a project of mine in a different fandom. I do not know the specific ratios for specific ranks (or Ratings) in Star Trek, another Fandom, or even reality. But,in my research, I have learned in the current US Navy structure, the average ratio of (all) Officers to Enlisted is 1 officer for every 10 enlisted. This of course is just an average, the size, purpose, or even budget of the ship can change that ratio to anywhere between 8% and 15%.

Answer (score 1):

Rank structure in Star Trek has been severely "retconned" multiple times. So I don't think there can be an answer.

On the Enterprise D, we had one [Lieutenant Commander](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Nella_Daren) popping out of the woodwork and disappearing again after having a speaking role in a single episode. That implies that Lieutenant Commanders are a dime a dozen -- nobody asks about Della Naren's opinions during Chains of Command, a just a few episodes earlier.

- In TOS, the most junior rank on the Enterprise was *Ensign.* Supposedly that was a reference to the astronauts of the era, commissioned officers in the USAF, USN, or USMC. With the possible exception of Yeoman Rand, an artifact of the time when the series was made.
- TNG got us Miles O'Brien, who was called *Chief*. After some [wobbling](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Miles_O'Brien) (scroll down to trivia) with "Chief of the Transporter Department," it was made clear that he was an NCO.
- Since then, other enlisted crew were introduced.

Comment: I'm not asking about the exact posts - I want the distribution of crew by rank. Even the ratio of officers to (non-NCO) crewmen is interesting!

Comment: Lieutenant Commander rank certainly never disappeared. Data held that rank during all seven seasons. Geordi is promoted to L.C. in Season 3. Troi held it until promotion to Commander in Season 7. Worf is promoted to it on the Holodeck scene in Star Trek: Generations.

Comment: @Tronman, what I meant is that **one** lieutenant commander could remain invisible/unremarkable until a specific episode, show up, and then return into obscurity. That implies she wasn't senior enough to to matter, before and after.

Comment: Ah, I see. I would think relatively few department heads would report to the captain directly, (only key systems) which would explain her prior absence. Lesser department heads like Stellar Cartography probably only report to the first officer.

Comment: Also ,you're drawing overly strong conclusion from the example of Nella Daren. We see very few people from the Sciences division, so it's not surprising there are some officers we barely notice. That doesn't happen (as) often with command and operations.

Comment: O'Brien was the _Tactical Officer_ on the Rutledge, a position held by a _Lieutenant_ on the Enterprise. It just needs to be accepted that the scriptwriters don't know anything about how ranks work.

Comment: @Gaius, in many navies, the position held by an officer on a large ship, will often be held by a more junior officer on a smaller ship. If the Rutledge was significantly smaller than the Enterprise, it would be probable an NCO did the same job on the Rutledge, that a Lieutenant did on the Enterprise. This even applies to ship captains, smaller ships are often "Captained" by Commanders or Lieutenants (Commander Cisco and the Defiant are a perfect example).